# Load SVG files in Fabric.js without grouping

Tags: svg, fabricjs

I am having an issue loading certain SVG files in Fabric.js without grouping its elements.

The screenshots on how the file is displayed on the canvas with and without grouping are shown. The used SVG file is part of the Fabric.js' SVG test collection used at [http://fabricjs.com/test/svg_import](http://fabricjs.com/test/svg_import/):

### **With grouping:**

[image: With grouping]

### **Without grouping:**

[image: Without grouping]

Both screenshots correspond to what it results when using the [Fabric.js' kitchensink](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink). However, I obtain the same results when writing my own program.

I have tried other files and they are shown with no problems whether the grouping is performed or not. Because of this, I suppose the distortions observed for this file on the non grouped version are due to some SVG elements (transformations or groups, perhaps?) that are not very well handled by the library's SVG parser.

Is it possible to avoid this issue under certain conditions? If so, what kind of SVG elements should be avoided to prevent files from presenting this problem?

Comment: Not sure if this is a silly question, but why don't you want groups ?

Comment: I have information visualisations on SVG and currently working on the "deconstruction" of them. In order to do that, I need to access the individual components of the vector file.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with fabric, but I would imagine you would need to flatten the transformations for every element then if no longer keeping the groups.

Comment: And what would the flattening process entail?

Comment: Taking the transforms of the groups and applying it to paths (including existing path transforms), or possibly applying the combined transforms to all of the path points (so there are no transforms left at all). Its worth noting though, if you remove groups, you are removing any semantics in svg.

Comment: fabricjs already flatten transformation correctly to elements, what it cannot do as of now is render those transformations correctly outside the group. You can still select the objects using some outside reference to them using something like groupedsvg.path[i]

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known "missing feature" in fabric.js

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1520

The library is not handling very good the object with a "transformMatrix" property set.

the "transformMatrix" property comes from parsing the transform attribute of the elements and the parents elements.

Normally the objects are grouped in a pathGroup object that is capable of handling the transforMatrix and give a correct rendering with the downside effect the objects cannot be moved individually or rotated/scaled.

There is a work in progress about this feature (by me) to solve this but is not complete yet.
You can download and try my branch here: 
https://github.com/asturur/fabric.js/tree/experimentalCBox

Is not perfect yet but is gonna be inserted in future fabric version to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I will try this from the branch you mentioned. However, I am currently using fabric.js 1.4.12. Can't update to further versions because the issue #1896 I reported on the fabricjs' main branch has not being solved and it is present in all the releases after the one I am using. Do you think I can just include the portion of code that does the magic I need from your branch? If so, could you point me to it?

Comment: Quite lot of code. would be easier to update to 1.6.0rc1 and backport the events problem. That we can try to solve anyway.